# How to set up stubs for PyRight

Tags: python, stub, pyright

I just installed PyRight through npm and use it as a lsp in neovim. I have a stubbed package that works in PyCharm.

```
mystub
  __init__.pyi
  object.pyi
  ...
```

I've tried setting the "stubPath" in my pyrightconfig.json to both the folder containing mystub, tried setting it to mystub. Also attempted renaming to mystub-stubs.

Is there any clear example of how to use existing stubs? I have zero interest in generating new ones etc. Stubs are already existing. I just need to make pyright load them

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why exactly. But [this](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/2158) seem to solved my issue.

So adding `"reportMissingModuleSource": false` to my config removed the error and I can get autocompletion etc from my stubs.